# Apache is Not Running From XAMPP control panel it cause error

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I have installed XAMPP (xampp-win64-3.2.2) on Windows 7 successfully. But unfortunately, the following error was found during running Apache from XAMPP Control Panel:[The Error of xampp Server Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaXGb.png)

Comment: This sounds like a binary mismatch between versions. If this was a clean install, I would recommend making sure that you completely uninstall, and reinstall.

Comment: i uninstalled and reinstall the xampp but again same error is displayed.